# how can I make a function that contains equations and apply it to different dataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas

I have my data like this

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,4), columns = list("ABCD"))
```

And I have equations that i applied in this data:

```
df["Vchd_D"] = df["A"].diff(1)*0.1
df["Vch_D"] = df["B"].diff(1)*0.20
df["Vecs_D"] = df["C"].diff(1)*0.50
```

If I have anothers dataFrame with different values and names, for example

```
Data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,4), columns = list("ABCD"))
DataWI = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,4), columns = list("ABCD"))
fex = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,4), columns = list("ABCD"))
```

How can apply my equations in the others DataFrame automatically?

Comment: You mean `df2` instead of `df` right?

Comment: Why not create a function that takes a frame, operates on it, and returns it?

Comment: Do you have the same column names in your DataFrames ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create a function where you define all your formula's in string format and we use `DataFrame.eval` to execute these formulas'. Then we apply these formulas to our dataframe:

```
def apply_formulas(df):

    func1 = 'A.diff(1)*0.1'
    func2 = 'B.diff(1)*0.2'  
    func3 = 'C.diff(1)*0.5'

    df["Vchd_D"] = df.eval(func1)
    df["Vch_D"] = df.eval(func2)
    df["Vecs_D"] = df.eval(func3)

    return df

dfs = [Data, DataWI, fex]

for df in dfs:
    df = apply_formulas(df)
```

Then for example if we print the `Data` dataframe:

```
print(data)

          A         B         C         D    Vchd_D     Vch_D    Vecs_D
0  0.569892  0.799825  0.441034  0.858675       NaN       NaN       NaN
1  0.681410  0.937648  0.457076  0.612711  0.011152  0.027565  0.008021
2  0.848778  0.491082  0.614710  0.049382  0.016737 -0.089313  0.078817
3  0.067191  0.936427  0.264359  0.710680 -0.078159  0.089069 -0.175176
4  0.377954  0.708957  0.368314  0.797688  0.031076 -0.045494  0.051978
```